# Electron/electron-packager angular desktop app - http requests to localhost server are refused and blocked

Tags: angular, deployment, electron, electron-packager

I have electron desktop app based on angular 8. My API is hosted in localhost. When app is sending a HTTP request, an error occurs in console: *Failed to load resource and unsafe port.* [Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9XP5.png)

I disabled the webSecurity but it didn't fix the issue. Here's the config file of electron:
[electron config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfLcJ.png)

Anyone had such problem with electron and requests to localhost?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to paste real code, for the that moment I have only those screens.

Answer (score 0):

The main process server listens on port 3000 and in the rendering process I ajax request the server of the local main process:

```
ajax.open('get', 'http://localhost:3000?name=' + "flag233");
```

Add "http://" to the request path！